# Creating a Html form that submits to a server via json

Tags: html, json, forms, server

I am trying to create a code with 4 user input fields which are then sent to a server via json. I am new to json but I am familiar with html so I am just a bit stuck on where to start.

Answer (score 2):

None of [the encoding types](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-enctype) supported by forms are JSON. There was [a proposal to add JSON](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-json-forms/) but work has been discontinued.

In order to send JSON you will have to use JavaScript and the [`XMLHttpRequest` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).

Start by [binding a submit event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to the form and, when it fires, [prevent the default behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault), use [the DOM](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Traversing_the_DOM) to read the information from the form, put it into an object, [convert it to JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and then send it with XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Thanks. That Really Helped. I was slightly confused but I saw where i went wrong.